# VSCode debugger in subprocess

Tags: python, fortran, subprocess, vscode-debugger

I am using a Python script to run functional tests of my program writen in Fortran. This script, after a previous part where inputs and other requirements are defined, calls the compiled executable file "master" through a subprocess:

`res = subprocess.call("master", shell=True)`,

And I am not able to properly configure the VSCode debugger to aid me through the compiled Fortran files.

I would like the VSCode debugger to automatically start and assist through the respective Fortran files once the Python script calls "master" through the subprocess.

I tryed to use the "attach" request in the "launch.json" file but it is not working:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "master",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "attach",
          "program": "/path/to/executable/master",
          "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
      },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome! As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)